# trying to create attribute only for ONE type of product

Tags: attributes, product-type

I have one problem, my code generates in every type of product my new attribute, why?
code for sql-install:

```
<?php
/* @var $installer Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

// Add attribute
$allowedProductTypes = array(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL
);

$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'terms_of_use', array(
    'group'             => 'General',
    'label'             => 'Terms of use',
    'apply_to'          => implode(',', $allowedProductTypes),
    'type'              => 'text',
    'sort_order'        => 4,
    'input'             => 'textarea',
    'default'           => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => true,
    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => true,
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'is_configurable'   => false
));
```

i dont understand when i have wrong code for what i need.... how i can create the attribute for a only ONE single type of product in code? thanks

Comment: You code should work. Could you check the table entry `catalog_eav_attribute` for your attribute. Specifically the `apply_to` field.

Comment: in column apply_to for table `catalog_eav_attribute` everything is null!!, and my attribute have been created in table `eav_attribute` and dont have a option apply_to there

Comment: Ok so the `apply_to` did not take effect. You could try either making a new set-up script to update attribute or remove the entry from `core_resource` and so the script will re-run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry for the `apply_to` field can be found in the table `catalog_eav_attribute`. This will be a sting separated by commas.

If this entry is NULL then your script did not run correctly. You could try either making a new set-up script to update attribute or remove the entry from `core_resource`table and so the script will re-run.

Comment: when i delete from core_resource is allow to rerun script., its ok for this, but how i can insert into table catalog_eav_attribute in sql-install.php? i have searched but not related, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to use the correct installer resource. Thats why apply_to and all other attributes of catalog_eav_attribute - table were not correctly set.

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
```